# How to find Outlook contact Unique ID?

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, office365, microsoft-dynamics

I want to see all fields of the contacts in outlook. Here the contacts are synchronized from D365. All fields that are coming from D365 will also be shown in outlook contacts (fields such as PrimaryId, CreatedBy, Owner, CreatedDate, modified By, modifiedDate etc.. )

When I open the contacts, not all fields are showing. How can I see all fields of the records?

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: you cannot view the primary key (guid) in form or view.. everything else can be seen in form or view..

Comment: Thank you @Vinoth..
when the scenario like to update the particular Record in outlook, How can we update them without knowing the contact record unique ID...?

Comment: use some developer tools like CRM JS Fiddle (Chrome addin) or Dev tools to see the Record GUID.. moreover you can identify with email address, right?

Comment: I'm trying to update the contact(which came from D365 contact record) details in outlook.

Comment: Read this: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscrmsupportblog/archive/2016/10/19/dynamics-crm-outlook-client-user-defined-fields

Comment: Do you want to see in CRM contact form (outlook client) or Outlook contact ?

Comment: @ArunVinoth I'm looking for outlook contacts Unique Id, which are synchd from CRM.

Answer (score 0):

You can open Advanced Find for Contacts and in there you can select additional columns.

Thanks Naveen. Except for ContactId, all the fields that you list should be available in a Contact Advanced Find view.

To get the ContactId for an individual record, you can get it from the URL of the record, or use the [Chrome Level Up](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/level-up-for-dynamics-crm/bjnkkhimoaclnddigpphpgkfgeggokam?hl=en) add-in, or [bookmarklets](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/leichtbewoelkt/archive/2015/04/13/dynamics-crm-bookmarklets-v2).

To get a list of Contact ID's you can export a view to Excel with reimport to get the ID's in the hidden column A, or create a FetchXML query and run it in [FetchXML Tester](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com), among other ways.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Aron.. I've gone through the Advanced Search,some fields related to the contacts are showing but not all fields are available. I want the fields of the contacts like ContactId, createdBy, CreatedOn,ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, Owner, Links etc..

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook client for CRM, follow these steps to view the fields.

[image]

> The EntryID is the unique identifier for each mail object in the user’s mailbox. This value is also used in the idMappingTable to relate the CRMID to the appropriate Outlook EntryID.

[image]

**crmEntryID** (*) corresponds to the Outlook EntryID of the object

**Crmid** corresponds to the created record’s unique GUID in CRM

[Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscrmsupportblog/archive/2016/10/19/dynamics-crm-outlook-client-user-defined-fields).